# Regex email validation: After @ i want up to 2 dots and 1 dash

Tags: javascript, regex, typescript

I'm trying to write a regex rule for an email validation. I want after the user type @ will be able to type .(dot) up to 2 times and -(dash) 0 or 1 times.

i wrote the following expression:
`/^[A-Za-z0-9_%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,3}$/`

i want emails like these to be valid:
info@domain.co.uk
info@domain-name.co.uk

and like these not valid:
info@domain.co.uk.fr
info@domain-name-kom.com

Comment: Why not take something tested. Your regex will not allow my email address

Comment: /[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}/igm

Comment: @Yahiya Multiline???

Comment: And then you will ask how to allow only non-consecutive dots, right? Please consider just adding simpler separate checks rather than the "cramming all conditions into single regex" approach.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks for your answer. What do you mean adding simpler separate checks?how can i do?

Comment: 2 or 3 characters for TLD is really poor, see [TLD list](https://www.iana.org/domains/root/db)

Comment: @Toto i know but i follow business rules for these verifications...It's wrong but it's ok for the company

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
/^\w+@(\w)+((\-)\w+)?(\.(\w+)){1,2}$/
```

Comment: No, do not try this, it won't work because it requires 1 dot to be in the host name and the optional `-` can only appear before `.`.

Comment: Please, have a look at these sites: [TLD list](https://www.iana.org/domains/root/db); [valid/invalid addresses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address#Examples); [regex for RFC822 email address](http://www.ex-parrot.com/~pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html)

Comment: This is matching `_123_123_@123-123.123.1_2_3`, not a valid address.